# Highchart Gantt remove Y Axis label

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-gantt

I am looking to hide Y Axis label for Highchart Gantt.

In my [fiddle](https://codepen.io/roit-sharma/pen/pobeZRB) that I attempted you will note that I am looking to completely remove Y Axis lable but my attempt creates empty column.[image: Remove Y Axis column from gantt chart]

```js
  yAxis: [{
        labels: {
        enabled: false
    },
  }]
```

Wasn't able to location anything in [Highcharts Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/gantt) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `visible` property:

```
    yAxis: [{
        visible: false
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L1gt67zp/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.visible

Comment: Unfortunately that removes the grid lines in Y axis altogether , I would like to keep the gridlines as well at least for the area that shows graph. I am looking to retain gridlines https://monosnap.com/file/KC22RrkJOVnhq8fS0uLXEZmhPjy6YZ

Comment: Hi @June, Ok, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yt2zhgd6/

Comment: Thank you. If it's not too much to ask I would also like to know how can I move xAxis label to bottom and have the labels center aligned . In my original question you will see my question in the screenshot as well  https://monosnap.com/file/EguHemC1nXzRA35y960VsEKqNzshk6

Comment: You need to use the `opposite` option, but also do something with a chart height because x-axis at the bottom is hidden by default. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/afd7qbun/

Comment: Thank you, Here is what I am trying to achieve https://monosnap.com/file/DVBWjvmVmOCSMnpf3HgNWR8uShTlmh , Not sure how much of this is possible :D i.e. rounded corners for each axis and background color(i.e. white). I am figuring out how to add margin between two X axis rows , so each axis is apart from each other , I tried margin property but that didn't worked out

Comment: Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xczvjr23/ You can add another series to imitate the background.

Comment: Would you know how to get values of any hovered bar , this.series.data have data for all the points where as I am only looking to retrieve start and end of the hovered graph only
```
  tooltip: {
   formatter: function() {
     console.log(this.series.data);
    }
  },
```
So let say there are 8 rows , User hovered on row-1 column - 2 (out of have 3 bar graphs / lines) row-1 have and I am only looking to get data of column 2 only

https://jsfiddle.net/yp6qx0hb/

Comment: Hi @June, Could you explain the problem more precisely? To get only the hovered point use: `this.point`

Comment: Can we use addSeries and have background in Line Chart as well http://jsfiddle.net/1epdowh3/29/ ? The example you shared is of Gantt Chart

Comment: What is the exact result you want to get?

Comment: Background to the line chart http://jsfiddle.net/1epdowh3/29/ like https://monosnap.com/file/DVBWjvmVmOCSMnpf3HgNWR8uShTlmh

Comment: Requirement is almost the same for what you suggested earlier for the gantt chart

Comment: Hi, yes you just need to use x-range series, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/rL4v0ho3/

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to add padding above and below x-range series? https://monosnap.com/file/M1w5ubuuWQznzA2C1vpTfzfO2NGF0r

Comment: Sure, use `groupPadding`, example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6k8jgv9f/